# Homework - C bit puzzle - Perform % using C bit operations (no looping, conditionals, function calls, etc)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm completely stuck on how to do this homework problem and looking for a hint or two to keep me going. I'm limited to 20 operations (`=` doesn't count in this 20).

I'm supposed to fill in a function that looks like this:

```
    /* Supposed to do x%(2^n).
       For example: for x = 15 and n = 2, the result would be 3.

       Additionally, if positive overflow occurs, the result should be the
       maximum positive number, and if negative overflow occurs, the result
       should be the most negative number.
     */
    int remainder_power_of_2(int x, int n){

      int twoToN = 1 << n;

      /* Magic...? How can I do this without looping? We are assuming it is a
         32 bit machine, and we can't use constants bigger than 8 bits
         (0xFF is valid for example).
         However, I can make a 32 bit number by ORing together a bunch of stuff.
         Valid operations are: << >> + ~ ! | & ^
       */

      return theAnswer;
    }
```

I was thinking maybe I could shift the `twoToN` over left... until I somehow check (without if/else) that it is bigger than x, and then shift back to the right once... then xor it with x... and repeat? But I only have 20 operations!

Comment: You have a mistake somewhere. If the result is supposed to be x%(2^n) (where “^” is exponentiation, not XOR), then 15%(2^4) is 15, not 3. So either the result is supposed to be x%n (15%4 is 3) or the example should say the result is 15, not 3.

Comment: Whoops! Thanks! Should be a 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since binary is base 2, remainders mod 2^N are exactly represented by the rightmost bits of a value.  For example, consider the following 32 bit integer:

```
00000000001101001101000110010101
```

This has the two's compliment value of 3461525.  The remainder mod 2 is exactly the last bit (1).  The remainder mod 4 (2^2) is exactly the last 2 bits (01).  The remainder mod 8 (2^3) is exactly the last 3 bits (101).  Generally, the remainder mod 2^N is exactly the last N bits.

In short, you need to be able to take your input number, and mask it somehow to get only the last few bits.

A tip: say you're using mod 64.  The value of 64 in binary is:

```
00000000000000000000000001000000
```

The modulus you're interested in is the last 6 bits.  I'll provide you a sequence of operations that can transform that number into a mask (but I'm not going to tell you what they are, you can figure them out yourself :D)

```
00000000000000000000000001000000 // starting value
11111111111111111111111110111111 // ???
11111111111111111111111111000000 // ???
00000000000000000000000000111111 // the mask you need
```

Each of those steps equates to exactly one operation that can be performed on an int type.  Can you figure them out?  Can you see how to simplify my steps? :D

Another hint:

```
00000000000000000000000001000000 //  64
11111111111111111111111111000000 // -64
```

Comment: Yes, right! I negate, then ?, then negate.
The problem is the step between the two ?s for me... so... hmmm.. maybe... + 1? ... right? aha! I think... right? Dunno going to try it out thanks!

Comment: @Silver: What much simpler, glaringly obvious thing could you do to get from step 1 to step 4 in one shot (that embarrasingly enough I didn't notice until after I submitted my post :D)?

Comment: @Silver: you should post your code when you're done.  I want to see what you come up with, and we can critique it.

Comment: For sure, I will, but it might be a little while because this isn't due for another two weeks (and I don't want to get in trouble so much). So you're algorithm is working great, except it always returns a positive result. Now... I know how to negate ~result + 1... but how to do it conditionally without conditionals

Comment: I added another hint.  Also, it might help to pull up the windows calculator, set it to programmer mode, and examine different numbers (you can side-by-side compare decimal and binary)

Comment: Hmmm... So I can definitely switch between positive and negative numbers (~someNumber + 1). The problem is... I need to only do that if x is negative. And I know it's negative if the most significant bit of x is 1. Which I can get with (x >> 31) & 0x00000001 (I can make 0x00000001 through several legal operations)... Now... if isNegative is 1... then I need to ~result + 1

Comment: 0x00000001 is just the value 1.  I have an ideone that computes the solution in 14 operations.  The problem you're trying to solve is, "how do I avoid branching." try searching SO for it. :D

Comment: @Silver Although `(x >> 31) & 1` very probably does what you want, right-shifting of negative values is implementation-defined behaviour, so `x >> s` _could_, technically, always result in 6 for `x < 0`. If the width of `unsigned int` is at least as large as the width of `int`, casting to `unsigned` before the shift is guaranteed to work. Unfortunately, that is not guaranteed by the standard, it is allowed that `UINT_MAX == INT_MAX`. So I don't see a bullet-proof way of getting an indication of negativity without a comparison `x < 0`. Nevertheless, in practice, it works.

Comment: @DanielFischer: as long as the implementation is on an x86 platform, it's sane enough to expect sign extension from arithmetic shifts (those performed on signed integers).  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift

Comment: @Wug Yes, thus "very probably". I just felt a bit like language-lawyering, particularly since it's a homework assignment.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** In decadic system to do a modulo by power of 10, you just leave the last few digits and null the other. E.g. 12345 % 100 = 00045 = 45. Well, in computer numbers are binary. So you have to null the binary digits (bits). So look at various bit manipulation operators (`&`, `|`, `^`) to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Since your divisor is always power of two, it's easy.

```
uint32_t remainder(uint32_t number, uint32_t power)
{
    power = 1 << power;
    return (number & (power - 1));
}
```

Suppose you input number as 5 and divisor as 2

```
`00000000000000000000000000000101` number
AND
`00000000000000000000000000000001` divisor - 1
=
`00000000000000000000000000000001` remainder (what we expected)
```

Suppose you input number as 7 and divisor as 4

```
`00000000000000000000000000000111` number
AND
`00000000000000000000000000000011` divisor - 1
=
`00000000000000000000000000000011` remainder (what we expected)
```

This only works as long as divisor is a power of two (Except for divisor = 1), so use it carefully.

Comment: I meant there's no need for that exception.  `remainder(n,0) == 0` is correct.